# React-Redux produces TypeError cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx

I have a JSX element that I am rendering with JSON data from a backend server. I am using Redux to manage my state. I make a find call to my state and match the JSON object by ID. I am then trying to extract a value out of that object using dot notation, but I get a TypeError undefined response. Here is my find and console.log

```
const getFundSources = fundingSources.find(f => f._id === match.params.id);
  console.log(getFundSources);
```

That outputs the following :

[image: pic of console.log]

however, if I add the following to my console.log:

```
 const getFundSources = fundingSources.find(f => f._id === match.params.id);
  console.log(getFundSources.fundingSourceName);
```

I get the TypeError undefined

[image: typeerror]

Here is my full code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { fundingSourcesDetails } from '../actions/fundingSourceActions';
import { projectsDetails } from '../actions/projectActions';

import FundingSourceIdentifiers from '../components/FundingSourceIdentifiers';
import FundingSourceGoals from '../components/FundingSourceGoals';
import Button from '../components/Button';
import ProjectSummary from '../components/ProjectSummary';
import SectionHeader from '../components/SectionHeader';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';

const FundingSourceScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const fundingSourceDetails = useSelector(state => state.fundingSourceDetails);
  const { fundingSources } = fundingSourceDetails;

  const projectDetails = useSelector(state => state.projectDetails);
  const { projects } = projectDetails;

  const getFundSources = fundingSources.find(f => f._id === match.params.id);
  console.log(getFundSources.fundingSourceName);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fundingSourcesDetails());
    dispatch(projectsDetails());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <FundingSourceIdentifiers />
      <FundingSourceGoals />
      <SectionHeader sectionName={`Projects for `} />
      <Button buttonName='Add Project' />
      <Table striped>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>Status</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
              <strong>Name</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
              <strong>Type</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
              <strong>Location</strong>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{}</tbody>
      </Table>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default FundingSourceScreen;
```

along with my reducer:

```
import {
  FUNDINGSOURCE_DETAIL_REQUEST,
  FUNDINGSOURCE_DETAIL_SUCCESS,
  FUNDINGSOURCE_DETAIL_FAIL
} from '../constants/fundingSourceConstants';

export const fundingSourceReducer = (
  state = { fundingSources: [] },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FUNDINGSOURCE_DETAIL_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, fundingSources: [] };
    case FUNDINGSOURCE_DETAIL_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, fundingSources: action.payload };
    case FUNDINGSOURCE_DETAIL_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and my action:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  FUNDINGSOURCE_DETAIL_REQUEST,
  FUNDINGSOURCE_DETAIL_SUCCESS,
  FUNDINGSOURCE_DETAIL_FAIL
} from '../constants/fundingSourceConstants';

export const fundingSourcesDetails = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: FUNDINGSOURCE_DETAIL_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/fundingsources');
    dispatch({
      type: FUNDINGSOURCE_DETAIL_SUCCESS,
      payload: data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: FUNDINGSOURCE_DETAIL_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message
    });
  }
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`fundingSources` is initialized as empty. You are trying to find an element before your API call returns.

Regarding your console log: There's probably an `undefined` above the cropped screenshot you posted.